# NuGet doesn´t reference installed package

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package

i have installed some NuGet-packages in VS and looked for it in Solution Explorer/MyProject/References. However NuGet-Packages is not referenced there.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you tell us which specific NuGet packages that you installed don't find the reference assemblies in References?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question right...

You're looking for why your package didn't get referenced?

1. Check the output window for why your package didn't get installed.
2. Check the packages folder for the solution.

More than likely there is some kind of reason for it not installing in the output window.

Answer (score 0):

(1)Check the install log on the Output window or the package manage window and make sure that whether these NuGet-packages are successfully installed.

(2)Confirm whether all NuGet-packages including any other .dll file in the package except the Resources.dll. If the package not have any assembly, just like tool package, the reference will not be added to the Explorer/MyProject/References. And assemblies ending with .resources are considered localization assemblies, and hence are not added as references. http://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-localized-packages. You could use the NuGet Package Explorer to view this packages, and check that whether it really has the dll files.

(3) Not very sure that how you install the package, but I think you could select different ways like using the package manage console windows or the Manage Nuget package window, you could select different way, view the result.

If still no help, just share us the VS Environment and the NuGet package, I will repro it in my side:)